# How to implement dynamic stack of image views with animation iOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, uigesturerecognizer

I had a requirement in one of my app, the requirement is to implement the dynamic unlimited stack of image views with the animation like mentioned in the following link : http://pinterest.com/pin/A3PGXgAQQOQD7xXa7kIAAAA/ in my current app using swift language. I have no idea at the moment, how to implement this type of functionality.Hence,please any suggestions and forward links ,how to implement this kind of animation which matches to my requirement, please post it.

Please look at the link of same content mentioned in the above link who don't have the pinterest : https://dribbble.com/shots/1667024-Events-deck-animation

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please post another link to the video. Pinterest can only be viewed by people with a Pinterest account. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) library. It doesn't offer the same behavior but maybe it's a good starting point.

Comment: @Fogmeister,Please look at the link of same content mentioned in the above link https://dribbble.com/shots/1667024-Events-deck-animation

Comment: @Gonji Dev,thanks for suggestion I tried iCarousel but not matching to current requirement